# Using value in 1 column to fill in values in 2 other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, date, data.table

When entering behavior data in a different system, I wrote the subjects in a form such as 3-2 (to mean rank 3 to rank 2).  I exported these to Excel, which took these entries as dates (so 2-Mar for this example).

I now have thousands of entries in this format.  I have added two columns ("Actor" and "Recipient") and would like to fill in the rank numbers for these, based on what is in the "Subject" column.

A couple of lines of what I'm hoping my R output will give me:

```
Subject Actor Recipient 
2-Mar   3     2
5-Jun   6     5
6-Feb   2     6
```

etc.

So I already have the "Subject" columns and need help figuring out code to fill in the "Actor" and "Recipient" columns.  Rank numbers only go up to 6.

I've tried a couple of things but just keep getting error messages... Any help with this would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: could you post a sample of your data please to make it possible to reproduce the problem, either code to produce dummy data or a sample of your data using the `dput()` function

Comment: Sure! The code in the next comment gives me the first 6 lines I currently have.  I'd like to fill in the Actor and Recipient columns as I mentioned above

Comment: `Subject <- c("2-Mar", "5-Jun", "6-Feb", "2-May", "2-Jun", "5-Feb")

Actor <- c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA")

Recipient <- c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA")

Behavior1 <- data.frame(Subject,Actor,Recipient)

Behavior1`

Comment: I've provided an answer - if this works as intended then please accept (and upvote) answer, if not please clarify what is wrong

Comment: You are incredible!!!! This worked!!! I tried up ticking but I guess it doesn't change the public up ticks.  I think this is because I'm new on here (just got an account to ask this question). But I really appreciate your quick help! Thank you!!

Comment: no worries-  I've added some more explanation to the answer to help you understand what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use `tstrsplit()` after converting to date format

```
# Recreate your data
x <- data.frame("Subject" = c("2-Mar", "5-Jun", "6-Feb"))

# Change the format of your Subject coumn
x[, "Subject"] <- format(as.POSIXct(x[, "Subject"], format = "%d-%b"), "%m %d")

# Split into the two strings
library(data.table) # to get tstrsplit() function
x[, c("Actor", "Recipient")] <- tstrsplit(x[, "Subject"], " ")

# Convert to numeric
x[, "Actor"] <- as.numeric(x[, "Actor"])
x[, "Recipient"] <- as.numeric(x[, "Recipient"])
```

This returns

```
> x
  Subject Actor Recipient
1   02 03     3         2
2   05 06     6         5
3   06 02     2         6
```

And if you want Subject in its original format

```
# Return Subject to original format
x[, "Subject"] <- format(as.POSIXct(x[, "Subject"], format = "%m %d"), "%d-%b")
```

Giving

```
> x
  Subject Actor Recipient
1  02-Mar     3         2
2  05-Jun     6         5
3  06-Feb     2         6
```

---

**Explained:**

Your vector/variable "Subject" was imported as a character-type *atomic vector* (atomic vectors are a 1 dimensional structure of one or more elements, where all elements must be the same *type*). The solution was to convert that something that R would interpret as a date using the `as.POSIXct(..., format = "...")` function, where format is telling R how the string is formatted ([see codes here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html)). I then wrapped that in the `format()` function, telling it to change the format to numeric months. That was then split into two columns using the `tstrsplit()` function, but R interpreted those as character-type data, so I converted them using the `as.numeric()` function to *double*-type data.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert `Subject` to date and extract month and year from it.

```
temp <- as.Date(df$Subject, "%d-%b")
df$Actor <- as.integer(format(temp, "%m"))
df$Recipient <- as.integer(format(temp, "%d"))
df

#  Subject Actor Recipient
#1   2-Mar     3         2
#2   5-Jun     6         5
#3   6-Feb     2         6
```

This can also be done using `lubridate` functions.

```
df$Actor <- month(temp)
df$Recipient <- day(temp)
```